# If the speed of wind at ground is 200 kn, could an Airliner land vertically if it's course is opposite to the wind's direction?

Tags: landing, wind

I'm not a pilote and my field is programming, but I was thinking about that question:
If the speed of wind at ground is 200 kn (just an example), could an Airliner land vertically (per reference to ground) if it's course is opposite to the wind's direction?

Comment: [Yes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WPyCywd4o5E). Only if the plane is able to fly at 200 kt, and I'm not sure the pilot will be able to stop the engine and/or turn to exit the runway. Why the downvote?

Comment: Hi. I did not downvote, someone else did. Thanks for the answer and I get your point for exiting the runway.